# Determine if AWS instance started by scheduler or manually

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tags, scheduler

Can a script query if the EC2 instance was started by the AWS Instance Scheduler?

I'd like to put code in rc.local that would run a script only if the instance was started by AWS Instance Scheduler.  If the instance was started manually from the web console, the script would not run.

Comment: Do u need just an indication if it is started by scheduler or manually or do you want assurance? If just indication, you can add predefined tags when started by the scheduler. If you want to ensure that manually users cannot create instances which looks like added by the scheduler, then need to create a specified role with which the scheduler initiated instances run. And thru policy ensuring that no one else can associate the role manually through permission in role, you

Comment: I just need indication, but thanks for pointing out that important distinction.

Answer (score 1):

Use Automated Tagging.

> The Instance Scheduler can automatically add tags to all instances it
>   starts or stops.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/instance-scheduler/components.html?shortFooter=true

You can retrieve current tags of an instance via [Describe Tags API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-tags.html#describe-tags). If, for example, you would invoke your script from "User Data", you could check if the tag added automatically by the Scheduler exists and skip the script.

Note, automatically added tags are removed during scheduled stop.

Comment: I was able to use your answer to install awscli and run aws configure.  Then install boto3 in python and use it to retrieve and manipulate the instance tags.  All is working.